# Signed Distance Function (or alternative to GLM/GAM) in R for sf geometries?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, spatial, gam

I have a set of sf geometries (LINESTRINGS, but equally useful to know a general solution for POLYGON, POINT etc.). These represent roads and, at the moment, I have a function which weights potential "candidate geometries" by their distance from the nearest road. This involved using sf's ST_LINE_SAMPLE to extract some points along the candidate geometry, and passing these into ST_NEAREST_FEATURE along with the road geometry to yield a set of LINESTRINGS from points to roads.

Computationally, this takes quite a long time - I have been reading up on and trialling ideas such as making a grid of points over the bounding box of the road geometry, calculating distances to roads, then creating a Generalised Additive Model (GAM) to predict any future points' distances, but the error is quite high as the road geometry is complex and the prediction surface is far too smooth without a high k-value in the smoothing parameter (which, for a low error, takes about the same length as just calculating the true distances).

Is there a methodology for producing a function, f(x, y, geom) = d, where x = longitude, y = latitude, geom = target geometry, d = distance to road, which allows for a high level of accuracy (less smooth) whilst also being a saving against the actual distances calculation? Signed distance functions seem useful, but I want to keep away from a discrete solution if at all possible.

Current code below:

```
distance_calc = 
  function(target_geom, points_to_weight, sample_size){
    library(mgcv)
    points = sf::st_sample(sf::st_bbox(target_geom) |> sf::st_as_sfc(), sample_size, type = "regular") |> sf::st_as_sf()
    
    dists = sf::st_coordinates(points) |> as.data.frame()
    dists$dist = sf::st_nearest_points(points, target_geom |> sf::st_combine()) |> sf::st_length() |> as.numeric()
    
    model = gam(dist ~ s(X,Y, k = 100), data = dists, method = "REML")
    out = points_to_weight
    out$prediction = predict(model, points_to_weight) |> as.numeric()
    out
  }
```

Above function works, but is too general.